# Problem app in play store after uploading

Tags: android

I upload my app in play store but the problem is my app does not install in many devices . The download reaches 99℅ and then stops or remain on hold It does not start downloading at all.

Help me please how can I fix it.

I didn't know what I do to correct the problem.

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. Your question seems off-topic and should more be asked directly to Play store's dev as it seems to be a bug for them. You can read [ask] for more informations